# Find ONLY existent records

Tags: c#, sql-server

Table is insert only table.

I need to find records that never got value 1.

How can I achieve that.

```
select count(distinct(userId)) from XXXX with(nolock)
where permission='1'  and value=0
```

This is not working because in table there is userId column. and some userId's has value 1 too. I need to find UserId's that never got value 1.

```
Id        UserId     Permission       Value
--        ------     ----------       ----- 
1         2          1                0    
2         2          1                1
```

When I execute my query, it brings count as 1.
But userId 2 has value 1 too.
I need to edit my query to bring the count as 0 if UserId has record for value 1.

Comment: What do you mean by a column only has 1 or 2 "records"? What is a "record"? Do you mean the **table** only has 2 *rows*? A `SELECT` will only return the rows that exist in said table. Perhaps the *real* problem is your (mis)use of the `NOLOCK` query hint and therefore you're getting the effects mentioned here: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: column can have 1 or 2 . its bit type.

Comment: A `bit` datatype can only store `1` or `0`. Storing a `2` in a `bit` would result in `1`.

Comment: We really need some sample data and expected results here. What you are saying doesn't make a lot of sense on its own.

Comment: You must a a list so use Any(x => value == 0)

Comment: its sql server How can I use like that @jdweng

Comment: If you have a table dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("UserId").Any(x => x.Field<int>("Value") == 1).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I *think* what you are after is a `HAVING` clause with a conditional aggregate:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT UserId
    FROM dbo.YourTable --WITH (NOLOCK) -- DO NOT use NOLOCK unless you understand what it is truly doing
    WHERE permission = 1 --This looks like an int, not a varchar
    GROUP BY UserId
    HAVING COUNT(CASE [Value] WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) = 0)
SELECT COUNT(UserId)
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

An `NOT IN` clause may be more performant:

```
select count(distinct(userId))
from XXXX 
with(nolock)
where userId NOT IN 
(SELECT userId FROM XXXX WHERE permission='1' and value=1)
```

Comment: I would, personally, suggest a `NOT EXISTS` when not knowing the User's data. Although one would *think* it safe to assume that `userId` does not hold any `NULL` values, if it does then this won't return any rows.

Comment: this needs WHERE permission='1' in main query i guess. Because there more than one permissiontype in the table. but it is working. Thanks.